# How do I style text input so it works on internet explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, input

I have tried EVERYTHING to be able to style JUST text inputs with internet explorer. Unfortunately IE doesn't support using [type=text] so that's out of the question.

I even added support for http://ie7-js.googlecode.com to my webpage with

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/lib/IE9.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

but no dice. I'd also like to get :hover working on my spans with IE but it doesn't work.

Any help on this would be appreciate so much. I'm new to the CSS scene and Internet Explorer keeps throwing me zingers. I even had to use a separate style sheet specifically for it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.class {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

<input type="text" class="class">
```

Just give it a class if you have to style it in IE.

That is if you want to target a specific text field only.

Comment: I don't want to have to give all my inputs a class.

Comment: Me either, can't wait to drop IE9 support